# How to remove everything except "01 - 10" pattern and vice-versa?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I want to remove everything including digits, characters, special characters from a file except `01 - 10` pattern. For example:

```
01 - 10
This is the first one :1
02 - 20
This is the second one -2
03 - 30
This is the third one "3
04 - 40
This is the forth one ;4
05 - 50
This is the fifth one .5
```

The regex that I have used is `[^\d\d\s-\s\d\d]`, keeping in mind to match everything except "01 - 10" pattern by selecting `\d\d\s-\d\d` and using character set charet(^).
But using this I'm getting:

```
01 - 10
     1
02 - 20
     -2
03 - 30
     3
04 - 40
     4
05 - 50
     5
```

But I want the result to be:

```
01 - 10
02 - 20
03 - 30
04 - 40
05 - 50
```

I.E., I want, 
01 - 10 pattern and, 
 not to include any individual :1 and -2 and "3 and ;4 and .5 as mentioned in the problem at the top.

And vice versa i.e. to select each line except the "01 - 10" pattern

eg:

```
This is the first one :1
This is the second one -2
This is the third one "3
This is the forth one ;4
This is the fifth one .5
```

I want to know the regex pattern for 01 - 10 case and vice versa so that I can keep both the separately generated results in separate files.

Comment: Use `^(?!0(\d) - \g{1}0$).*` for matching and replace with empty string.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but can you please elaborate so that I can understand how this regex is working

Comment: I am using ATOM text editor

Comment: I have one more query regarding this - is it applicable for pattern like 01:10 too with slight modifications like ^(?!0(\d):\g{1}0$).*    ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^(?!\d{2}\h*[:-]\h*\d{2}\h*$).*[\r\n]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N9xmRx/5)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!`: Start negative lookahead

  - `\d{2}`: Match 2 digits
  - `\h*[:-]\h*`: Match 0 or more horizontal whitespaces followed by `:` or `-` followed by 0 or more horizontal whitespaces
  - `\d{2}`: Match 2 digits
  - `\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
  - `$`: End of the line
- `)`: End negative lookahead
- `.*`: Match anything
- `[\r\n]`: Match 1+ of line breaks
- Replacement is an empty string to remove all matching lines

**Reverse Removal**

To remove digit pair lines you can use:

```sh
^(?=\d{2}\h*[:-]\h*\d{2}\h*$).*[\r\n]+
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/N9xmRx/6)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking out time to explain the detailed working of your provided regex...It's really helpful...have a great day!!!

Comment: Just a clarification. Do you want to keep lines such `12:89` also? Because questions mentions `except 01 - 10 pattern`

Comment: Yeah, just clicked that what if the pattern is like 12:89, so that I can better understand that  how the regex is working...but thank you once again for your detailed explanation

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear. Using this regex it will remove lines such as: `02 - 29` but accepted answer will not remove it. Questions says `except 01 - 10 pattern` so I wanted to understand which one is your expected behaviour?

Comment: @AkshayaAmar Are you specifically interested in the pattern of `0x - x0` or any two-digit numbers separated by a hyphen? Based on the examples in your question, the former appears to be true. Note that the other answer will keep any two-digit numbers separated by ` - ` (e.g., `55 - 23`). Is that what you want?

Comment: @41686d6564 I want any two-digit numbers separated by hyphen or a colon and not particular `0x - x0` pattern. I just gave an example for hyphen so as to get the basic idea of how it is done and with some minute modifications it will work for colon and other cases too...

Comment: Just to get a basic idea, I used an example where hyphen `-` was used, but by doing slight modification it should work in case of colon `:` as well. I have a file which is having either all `12 - 34` pattern i.e. any `two-digit number - any two digit number` or  all `56 : 78` pattern i.e. any `two-digit number : any two digit number` and not having both `-` and ':' simultaneously . I hope now it has become clear to you

Comment: @anubhava: I have edited my question because I want to know how to select 01 - 10 and separate them without feeding a new line after every pattern and also I want to know the regex for vice-versa case. I have explained the requirement in the question itself.

Comment: You can [use this](https://regex101.com/r/N9xmRx/3) and [this](https://regex101.com/r/N9xmRx/4)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
^(?!\d\d\s-\s\d\d).*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/t4qrh0/1

Comment: thank you for your quick response...can I use this same regex ^(?!\d\d\s:\s\d\d).* for pattern like 01:10 too?

Comment: ^(?!\d\d\s:\s\d\d).* will work if it's "01 : 10" (with spaces), but if it's 01:10 (no space) then you need ^(?!\d\d:\d\d).*

Comment: You can just open the link I have posted and play with the regex, you'll see real time result :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification and the link too...Have a great day!!!